# Why this code is working with priority queue but not with Set

Tags: c++

This is the question: Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the k most frequent elements. You may return the answer in any order.

Now, when i'm using set this is not working

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map<int,int>mp;
        for(auto x:nums){
            mp[x]++;
        }
        set<pair<int,int>>st;
        for(auto x:mp){
            st.insert({x.first,x.second});
        }
        vector<int>ans;
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            auto a = *(st.begin());
            int x = a.first;
            ans.push_back(x);
            st.erase(a);
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

I was expecting this to work with dijkstra using set

Comment: "[I]s not working" is not a good enough description. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Then read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Your set is sorted by element first, then frequency, in increasing order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work for finding the k most frequent elements in an integer array `nums`. However, it may not correctly handle cases where two elements have the same frequency. If that's not a concern for your specific use case, the code should be fine.

Otherwise, you can try

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map<int, int> mp;
        for (auto x : nums) {
            mp[x]++;
        }

        // Use a custom comparator to compare pairs based on frequency
        auto comparator = [](const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b) {
            return a.second > b.second;
        };
        
        // Use a priority queue (min-heap) to maintain the top k frequent elements
        priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(comparator)> pq(comparator);

        for (auto x : mp) {
            pq.push(x);
            if (pq.size() > k) {
                pq.pop();
            }
        }

        vector<int> ans;
        while (!pq.empty()) {
            ans.push_back(pq.top().first);
            pq.pop();
        }

        // Reverse the result to get the most frequent elements first
        reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());

        return ans;
    }
};
```